# Chat: Issue in Communicating On Chat

Tags: bug, support, status-completed, chat

In the chat system i was able to talk.  However, due to some strange issue in the system, the box in which I can type a message into disappeared, and I cannot get it back.  Applies to any system I log into, and I have more than the required rep to talk in chat.

Any ideas on how to resolve this?

Comment: can you provide a screenshot?

Comment: This was resolved.  A mod accidentally flagged my post, which blocked me for 30 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While the behaviour was indeed correct as you have noted, your report made me look at what the screen looks like for suspended users.

It indeed just removed the input box without any further notice, which was simply an oversight. This is fixed now; there's now a message explaining the issue.

Comment: Thanks much, I was wondering exactly why I just randomly lost access, and the mod who flagged me apologized because he forgot he was a mod for a sec :P